# ImportError: No module named 'django', ImportError: Couldn't import Django

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm new to python, when I run this command I'm getting this error

```
plutus@plutus-probook /var/www/html/python_learn/myproject $ python manage.py startapp webapp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    import django
ImportError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

If I try to install django, then this is the result

```
plutus@plutus-probook /var/www/html/python_learn/myproject $ pip install django
Requirement already satisfied: django in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.11.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from django) (2017.2)
```

Comment: please use virtualenv

Comment: Your suggestion would be useful

Answer (score 1):

This could be because you might have [multiple versions of python and pip lying around](https://xkcd.com/1987/). Try this

```
python -m pip install django
```

This will make sure you install django for the same python version which is invoked when you call python on the terminal.